# Optimal transport between two matrices

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, measure-concentration, optimal-transportation, wasserstein-distance

I'm investigating the use of optimal transport to define a distance between non-negative matrices that satisfy the condition $\mathbf e^\top\mathbf M\mathbf e = 1$ (i.e., the sum of all elements in the matrix is 1). While I've come across the application of optimal transport for distributions (e.g., the Wasserstein metric), I couldn't find resources on its application to matrices.

Could anyone guide me toward references or methodologies that cater to this specific scenario?

Comment: Are the entries of the matrices nonnegative? Also, what is the motivation here?

Comment: Have you tried vectorizing the matrices and considering them as vectors of $n^2$ elements?

Comment: @IosifPinelis, Yes all of them are non-negative. The motivation is that I have 9*9 matrices representing heat maps and I want to cluster them.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni No I can't because then they are not matrices and the distances will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

In addressing this problem, one approach to consider is conceptualizing the matrix cells as points in a 2D Cartesian coordinate system. Specifically, treat each matrix cell coordinates $(i,j)$ as points and the value of the cell as the mass located at that point. With this representation, you can then apply methods from [Discrete Optimal Transport](https://remi.flamary.com/demos/transport.html).

Comment: "matrices inherently possess discrete distances. Translating the problem into a continuous space could introduce challenges and might not yield the best solution." -- What are "discrete distances"? How can matrices "possess" them? What kind of "translating"? Into what "continuous space"? What "challenges"? What is "the best solution"?

Comment: @losifPinelis, thanks for your comment. By "better solution," I mean a more efficient algorithm. However, upon your other questions, with more thinking, now I'm unsure if the discrete nature of matrices (that [i, j] are always integers) implies the existence of a faster method for solving this OT.